# Django template variable has wrong value / Javascript in HEAD not executed

Tags: python, django, jquery-mobile, django-templates

I have a Django template base.html:

```
// inside the javascript
var this_page = "{{ this_page }}";

// inside the HTML part
{% ifnotequal this_page "home" %}
...Some HTML...
{% endifnotequal %}
```

The part inside the javascript area is incorrect. Actually, Firebug shows me in the HTML tab:

```
var this_page = "home";
```

but if I look into the GET inside the Console tab, Firebug shows:

```
var this_page = "about";
```

which would be correct, but debugging shows that 'this_page' is set to 'home'.
I also tried it:

```
{% ifnotequal this_page "home" %}
do some javascript
{% endifnotequal %}
```

but that did also not work correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: This problem only occurs when I access this page via a link. If I access the "about" page directly, I do not have this problem.

Testing on Ubuntu, Firefox 6.0.2, on 'runserver'

Comment: Are you saying `{{ this_page }}` outputs "home" but `{% ifequal this_page "home" %}foo{% endifequal %}` does not print foo? Is the html and javascript in the same file? Are you 100% certain the variables are being passed into these templates?

Comment: @Yuji: Yes, javascript section and html are in one file. I have found out that on the "about"-page if I have `{% ifequal this_page "home" %}foo{% endifequal %}` inside the javascript section, "foo" is printed (incorrect), while inside the html section, it is not (correct). I assume, that this has more something to do with the browser, since this makes no sense. But I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem had (perhaps not surprisingly) nothing to do with the question. Apologies that I asked into the wrong direction.

Since I use jquery mobile, it behaved not as I expected: the body content (per default) is loaded per ajax on page change, while the head part is only loaded once.

The solution to the problem I have found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562461/refresh-a-section-after-adding-html-dynamically-to-jquery-mobile).

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript is a client-side language. The HTML of your template is rendered by the python on server side so you cannot change rendered variable's value through java script code. In your case **this_page** is rendered html variable and `var this_page = "{{ this_page }}";` defines a separate javascript variable and does not change the rendered html **this_page** variable. So firebug is correct.

You can use Ajax for this purpose if you want to dynamically change the rendered HTML.

Comment: On the server side, I put {"this_page" : "about"} into the templage tags, so whatever the left hand side will be, the right hand should be "about". No?

Comment: thanks, your answer was going into the right direction. The problem lied with using jquery mobile, which did not reload the head as I expected. I would give a +1, but I can't.