# jQuery mobile how to apply a single button theme to all buttons

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, button

I want all of my (data-role="button")'s to have a theme of (`data-theme="b"`) light blue..

I know people who write jQuery don't seriously waste their lives retyping this thousands of times. So is it applied like a .css property is defined and I just need to put it in my header or link another .js file to it?

in CSS I know it would look like `.button { data-theme: b; }` easy as pie. and smart people save time by doing a task that needs to be repeated over and over, in one place.

but in jquery its seems to always be written like..

```
<div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-theme="b">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-role="button"data-icon="arrow-r" data-theme="b">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#videos" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-theme="b">Videos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#photos" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-theme="b">Photos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tweets" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-theme="b">Tweets</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

is there a way around this or is it smarter to just leave it as the default theme?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you aren't just styling it with CSS using the attribute selector (`a[data-role="button"] { ... }`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able achieve this with a JQuery selector combining the `<a>` tag and the `button` attribute.

```
$("a[data-role='button']").attr("data-theme","b");
```

**EDIT**

Apparently, it can be a little tricky to get the JQuery Mobile theme to refresh. [It's be asked on SO a few times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562461/refresh-a-section-after-adding-html-dynamically-to-jquery-mobile); [here's some info. from the JQM FAQ](http://jquerymobiledictionary.pl/faq.html).

Comment: On a side note, is there any way I can make this theme apply before the document is ready?