# How to trigger something after the view is updated?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, angularjs

Since in jQuery mobile, it adds some class to a component, everything looks nice. But when I update the array in AugularJS, the content appears on the page but doesn't get the classes jQuery adds.

So I want to refresh the component AFTER the view is updated, not after the value is changed. How can I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562461/refresh-a-section-after-adding-html-dynamically-to-jquery-mobile

Comment: What are you updating, a listview?

Comment: @tymeJV Yes, a listview.

Comment: Are you adding a new listview `ul` or adding items to an existed listview?

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a list view, trigger a refresh:

```
$('#mylistID').listview('refresh');
```

Comment: When I do it in app.js, it says "cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'" :(

Comment: Make sure you're inside your `pageinit` func.

Comment: so is it `refresh` inside `$scope.$watch`, and `$scope.$watch` inside `pageinit`?