# jQuery Mobile creating a Collapsible set dynamically via ajax does not apply styling

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamically adding collapsible elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214538/dynamically-adding-collapsible-elements)

I am dynamically creating a Collapsible set and adding it to the page using `$('#myID').html(htmlcode)`. The styling is not being applied to the page. How can I get jQUery mobile to apply it styling?

(I am using `$.get()` to query a web service.The content that returned I am looping through to create the markup)

Comment: Hey, nice question. Do you already have found a solution to this? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This is working for me. My ajax returns a bunch of h3's which I insert into a collapsible div and append a p tag for the content.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.get(my_url, function(data) {
        var content = $('div[data-role="content"]').html(data);
        $('h3').each(function(h3_element) {
            var coll = $('<div class="ui-collapsible-contain" name="blog"  data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">');
            coll.append($(this));
            coll.append($('<p>'));
            content.append(coll);
        });
        content.trigger( "create" );        
    });

});
```

Comment: and no, refresh trigger didn't work either...

Answer (score 3):

Already answered in [Jquery Mobile Collapsible Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226788/jquery-mobile-collapsible-content)

To initialize your div correctly after preventing the default init formating, you'll have to use something like $("a way to select your div").trigger('create'); as specified here:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

Answer (score 1):

```
$content.find(":jqmData(role=collapsible)").collapsible();
```

Comment: This was how my team was doing it at first, but it caused problems with the styling when performed on a `collapsible-set` as well as the `collapsible`s inside. Using `.trigger('create')` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

[Collapsible content and Ajax loading](http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2011/4/5/Collapsible-content-and-Ajax-loading-with-jQuery-Mobile)