# JQuery Mobile not applied

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-fieldset, jquery-mobile-slider

I'm having some troubles with JQueryMobile because i want to implement some widgets but the themes and color of the widgets is not well-implemented.

Here's a photo to show what's happening:
[image]

And the correct widget for example would be that:

[image]

If i add the jquerymobile widgets dynamically then the theme is not well-added but if the html is already on a file (not added dynamically with javascript) the theme looks well. Here's the code I use to add the widgets:

```
function cesta_insert_html(){
    var cesta_bought = $('body').data('cesta_list');
    cesta_bought.forEach(function(element, index){
        image = get_product_info(element[0].id, 'data' + $('body').data('clicked_listview_item'));
        $('#cesta_view').append('<div data-role="collapsible-set" id="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="c"><div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false"><h3 id="title_collapsible">'+image.pname+'</h3><center><div id=image_cesta><img src=data:imajpeg;base64,'+image.pimage+' alt="image"></div><div data-role="fieldcontain"><fieldset data-role="controlgroup"><input type="range" class="slider" name="slider" value="0" min="0" max="100" data-highlight="false"></fieldset></div></center><div class="ui-grid-a"><div class="ui-block-a"><a id=SaveChangesCesta data-role="button" type="submit" >Guardar cambios</a></div><div class="ui-block-b"><a id="DeleteCesta" type="submit" >Eliminar de cesta</a></div></div></div></div><br><br>');
    });
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it is me, but can you show/comment on what *should* happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/6nG2n/

You are combining several different widgets, to enhance their markup you should run trigger('create').

Read more about it in my other answer: **[jQuery Mobile: Markup Enhancement of dynamically added content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14550417/1848600)**

```
$('[data-role="content"]').append('<div data-role="collapsible-set" id="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="c"><div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false"><h3 id="title_collapsible">Image</h3><center><div id=image_cesta><img src=data:imajpeg;base64,Image alt="image"></div><div data-role="fieldcontain"><fieldset data-role="controlgroup"><input type="range" class="slider" name="slider" value="0" min="0" max="100" data-highlight="false"></fieldset></div></center><div class="ui-grid-a"><div class="ui-block-a"><a id=SaveChangesCesta data-role="button" type="submit" >Guardar cambios</a></div><div class="ui-block-b"><a id="DeleteCesta" type="submit" >Eliminar de cesta</a></div></div></div></div><br><br>');   
$('#index').trigger('create');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check these similar questions out: [jQuery Mobile creating a Collapsible set dynamically via ajax does not apply styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218001/jquery-mobile-creating-a-collapsible-set-dynamically-via-ajax-does-not-apply-sty)
[Dynamically adding collapsible elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214538/dynamically-adding-collapsible-elements)
[Dynamically adding collapsible elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214538/dynamically-adding-collapsible-elements)

After adding something dynamically in JQuery mobile you can apply the markup by calling a create or refresh method.

Try calling

```
$("collapsible").collapsible()
```

after appending the collapsible to initialize it.

Comment: It's an error of the initialization of sliders: cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

Comment: Call '.slider()' instead of '.slider("refresh")'.   

'.slider' should initialize the element. Then when you update it dynamically in the future you can use '.slider("refresh")'