# jQuery dynamic element - styling not being applied

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic, styling

I have 2 `Button` which when clicked either add a new paragraph or remove a current paragraph. This is done using `jQuery`. I am also using `jQuery` to change the color of the paragraph text from black to red on `hover`. The problem that I am having is that after I add a new paragraph with `jQuery`, the hover effect is not being applied to it. It works for the original paragraphs but not for the ones that are being created dynamically.

When I look at the `source code` of the page I see that the original paragraphs have inline styles applied to them but not the ones I added via `jQuery`. I have been looking online for the last hour trying to find a solution but so far none have worked for me. I found some similar questions but the solutions either didn't work for me or I wasn't applying them correctly. The thing is that I literally started learning `jQuery` a couple of hours ago and therefore cannot be sure if i'm fixing something or making it worse. Also, most of the questions I have looked at are to do with `jQuery` Mobile which confuses me further as i am working on my PC.

http://jsfiddle.net/2Xh75/

HTML

```
<button>Add line</button>
<button>Remove line</button>

<div id="p_wrap">
    <p> Original Line </p>
    <p> Original Line </p>
    <p> Original Line </p>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Add line   
    $("button:nth-of-type(1)").click(function(){
        $("#p_wrap").append("<p>New Line</p>");
    });

    //Remove line
    $("button:nth-of-type(2)").click(function(){
    $("p:last-of-type").remove();
    });

    //Hover effect
    $("p").hover(
      function(){
          $(this).css("color", "red");
      },
      function(){
          $(this).css("color", "black");
      }
    );

}); // Document Ready End
```

Here are some of the questions I have already looked at:

[Forcing jQuery Mobile to re-evaluate styles/theme on dynamically inserted content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297470/forcing-jquery-mobile-to-re-evaluate-styles-theme-on-dynamically-inserted-conten)

[jQuery Mobile does not apply styles after dynamically adding content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999436/jquery-mobile-does-not-apply-styles-after-dynamically-adding-content?lq=1)

[jquery styles not applied in dynamically creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012447/jquery-styles-not-applied-in-dynamically-creation)

I apologize in advance since this is probably a noob question but it has me stumped and I would appreciate any help.

-Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery.Hover not working for dynamic Element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972389/jquery-hover-not-working-for-dynamic-element)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `.on` as it will bind new elements that you will append dynamically in the DOM

```
$(document).on('mouseover', 'p',  function () {       
 $(this).css("color", "red");
}).on('mouseout', 'p',  function () {       
 $(this).css("color", "black");
});;
```

Comment: +1 - you can also pass an object of events to `on()` http://jsfiddle.net/2Xh75/15/

Answer (score 1):

The elements you selected was not existing when you define jQuery selector for "p", you should use "on" function:

```
$("p").on({
   mouseenter: function() 
   {
      //mouseover css
   },
   mouseleave: function()
   {
      //mouseleave css
   }
});
```

Comment: It works just for static elements. Question is about dynamicly appended elements.

Comment: @billyonecan is right, this doesn't work for dynamic elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use css for this type of hover effect. The reason it doesn't work with jquery is because your not delegating the event to a parent by using the `.on()`.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2Xh75/3/)

```
p:hover
{
    color:red
}
```

Comment: I know I can do it with CSS, I just wanted to know if there was a jQuery solution. I thought that since I just started learning it maybe I was missing something. Thanks anyway for the speedy reply

Answer (score 0):

You can do the hover effect purely with CSS --- almost always the better choice:

```
#p_wrap > p:hover
{
    color: red
}
```

Also I'd advise refactoring the click handlers using the newer preferred `on` syntax:

```
$("button:nth-of-type(1)").on("click", function(){
    $("#p_wrap").append("<p>New Line</p>");
});
```